# Unable to access value of const char array

Tags: python, c, string, segmentation-fault, ctypes

Say I have the following code in a C library called `libmylib.so`:

```
static char mystr[9];

/* somewhere else this array is populated with a value 8 bytes or less */

const char *
get_mystr (void)
{
  return mystr;
}
```

From the Python interpreter, I call the following

```
from ctypes import *
mylib = CDLL('libmylib.so')
```

to load the library. Now, I set a variable equal to `mystr`

```
x = mylib.get_mystr()
```

If I try to check the value of `x` or any properties of it, I get a segmentation fault. Even using `TAB` after typing `x.` at the prompt to see what fields/functions are available results in a segfault.

What's going on?

EDIT: If I check `x` itself, I get a memory address, as expected. If I try to check `x.value` or look at the available fields, it crashes.

EDIT 2: I tried checking if the `static` declaration was the source of my problems, but it seems to behave the same way without it.

Comment: The default `restype` is `c_int`. As a function result this gets converted to a native Python integer, which won't have a `value` attribute. Set `get_mystr.restype = c_char_p` to convert it to a Python string instead. This assumes that `mystr` is null-terminated.

Comment: However, this doesn't explain the segfault, which must be due to a fault elsewhere in your program. You need to use a debugger such as gdb in Linux or cdb in Windows to print a stack trace.

Comment: You say "somewhere else this array is populated with a value 8 bytes or less", but (a) are you sure about that and (b) is it properly null-terminated?  If it's not null-terminated, somebody's going to run out to infinity (or at least well past the end of the `mystr` array) looking for the `'\0'`.

Comment: Testing this using a small C program to call the same code appears to work. Setting the `restype` has had no effect; CPython is determining that `get_mystr()` has returned an `int`instead of a `c_char_p`. If I try to convert it to a pointer using `c_char_p.from_address(mylib.get_mystr())` and then check the value, I get a segfault. @SteveSummit Yes, it is populated from a `strcpy()` call after first checking that the input is 8 or fewer in length. `strcpy()` is documented to terminate the string.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't read closely enough. I was trying to set the restype of the Python wrapper function and not that of the C function. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Your use of `from_address` has two problems. First and foremost, you're basically treating the result as a `char **`. It's dereferencing the returned pointer to get the address value of a `c_char_p` instance. The right way to do this is just `c_char_p(address)`, or use `cast(address, c_char_p)`. Secondly, since the default `restype` is `c_int`, the result is no longer a valid pointer in a 64-bit process. Either one of these problems can lead to a segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eryksun pointed out that the `restype` of the C function was defaulting to `int` and being resolved to a Python integer.

By calling `mylib.get_mystr.restype = c_char_p`, it now properly resolves to a `bytes` object which can be decoded properly.

Comment: @alk Actually, I have to wait 2 days after posting my own answer to accept it. Ask on meta if you're not sure why this is the case.